# Documenting a package that defines a function with the same name

Tags: r, package, roxygen2, rd

I am writing a package named `foo` that defines an S3 class named `foo` with various S3 methods. I have written a constructor function `foo()` that returns a `foo` object. It seemed practical to name the class after the package, and the function after the class, and I hoped that:

- `package?foo` would bring up the package help page.
- `?foo` and `?foo::foo` would bring up the function help page.

But what happens is that:

- Both `package?foo` and `?foo` bring up the package help page.
- Only `?foo::foo` brings up the function help page.

Is there a way to give a package and a function the same name that produces my desired behaviour?

Currently I have a file `foo_package.R` like this:

```r
#' The foo package
#' 
#' A very useful package.
#' 
#' @docType package
#' @name foo
NULL
```

and a file `foo.R` like this:

```r
#' The foo function
#' 
#' A very useful function.
#' 
#' @param x A data frame.
#' @return A foo object.
#' @export
foo <- function(x) {
  structure(x, class = c("foo", "data.frame"))
}
```

Any hints are appreciated...

Comment: The convention seems to be to use `?foo-package` for the package help (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-packages) and [here](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/861)) and `?foo` for the function help. The `type?topic` syntax is specific to S4 generics. You can't really change how that works from your package.

Comment: Following the notes under "Packages" in `vignette("rd")`, suggested in your second link, I now get the package help with `package?foo` and the function help with `?foo`, as desired. However, `?foo-package` brings up `?"-"`, the help for arithmetic operators!

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. It would be `?"foo-package"` since you can't have operators in help topic names. But that's the one that should come up when you do `help(package="foo")`

Comment: `?"foo-package"` works. Thanks - I'll synthesize an answer with corrected roxygen blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [second link](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/861) in @MrFlick's comment, which points to the text under "Packages" in `vignette("rd")`, I was able to get the expected behaviour.

`foo.R` is unchanged, but `foo-package.R` now reads:

```r
#' The foo package
#' 
#' A very useful package.
#' 
#' @docType package
#' @keywords internal
#' @aliases foo-package
"_PACKAGE"
```

Now, as desired:

- `package?foo` and `?"foo-package"` bring up the package help.
- `?foo` and `?foo::foo` bring up the function help.